# VideoJS error ie9 mp4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-video, video.js

I have an asp.net MVC 4 controller that provides the mp4,

```
public ActionResult GetVideoForEvent(int eventId)
    {
        var videoPath = "pathToVideo";
        var videoFileInfo = new FileInfo(videoPath);

        return new RangeFilePathResult("video/mp4", videoFileInfo.FullName, videoFileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc, videoFileInfo.Length);
    }
```

And a video player in a partial view,

```
@model int
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

    <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="none" width="320" height="256" data-setup="{}"  >
        <source type="video/mp4" src="@Url.Action("GetVideoForEvent", new { eventId = Model})">
    </video>
```

This works for ie8 and ie10 but not ie9.
The problem only occurs when using videojs, if I used the just the html5 `<video>` the video plays.
Also if I change the source to be a direct link to a file on iis, the video plays.

Output from ie9 console:

```
LOG:  
LOG: Video Error[object Object]
```

What is causing the error when using videojs and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. By only using videojs if the browser is ie 8, the video plays on ie8, 9, 10 and Google chrome.

The video player does look different on each browser though.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check your MIME types for mp4 files are correct and that the video is encoded correctly.

I found the debugging guide on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/07/20/html5-video-not-working-in-ie9-some-tips-to-debug.aspx) website to be very helpful.